# Permission Issue with Bundled FFmpeg in Kotlin Jetpack Compose Desktop App

Tags: kotlin, ffmpeg, permissions, desktop-application

I am developing a Kotlin Jetpack Compose Desktop application that utilizes FFmpeg for video processing. The FFmpeg and FFprobe binaries are included in my application resources. However, I am facing a permission issue where the FFmpeg does not have execution permissions when the application is distributed, even though it had the necessary permision

Error Message:

```
Error: Could not create instance for [Singleton:'record.video.domain.VideoRepository']
```

Relevant Code Snippets:

```
import java.io.File

object FFmpegUtils {
    val FFmpegPath: String by lazy {
        File(System.getProperty("compose.application.resources.dir"), "ffmpeg").path
    }

    val FFprobePath: String by lazy {
        File(System.getProperty("compose.application.resources.dir"), "ffprobe").path
    }
}
```

```
class VideoRepositoryImpl : VideoRepository {
    override fun getVideosByPath(filePath: String): List<Video> {
        val videos = getFilesWithExtension(filePath, listOf("mp4", "mkv", "avi", "mov"))

        return videos.map { path ->
            Video(
                name = path.fileName.toString(),
                path = path.toString(),
                size = getFileSize(path),
                date = getFileDate(path),
                duration = getVideoDuration(path),
                thumbnail = getVideoThumbnail(path)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

```
object FileHelper {
    fun getFilesWithExtension(directoryPath: String, fileExtension: List<String>): List<Path> {
        return Files.walk(Paths.get(directoryPath))
            .filter { fileExtension.any { extension ->
                    it.fileName.toString().endsWith(extension)
                }
            }
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .toList()
    }
}
```

Attempted Solutions:

Manually changing file permissions post-installation.

Questions:

How can I programmatically set permissions for FFmpeg when my application is first installed or launched?
Is there a common pattern or practice in Kotlin Jetpack Compose Desktop applications for handling bundled binaries and their permissions?
Additional Context:

The application is intended to be cross-platform (Windows/macOS/Linux).
I am using the ffmpeg-cli-wrapper by bramp: [https://github.com/bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper]([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4bx1.png))
Any help or guidance from the community would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you know that file permissions are the problem?  Are there any further messages (errors, stack trace) after the error line you quote?

Comment: When i use redistributable in intellij idea the error is permission denied and as i stated when i give ffmpeg permission manually in the application folder it works fine